# SQL Server / SSRS: Calculating monthly average based on grouping and historical values

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need to calculate an average based on historical data for a graph in SSRS:

- Current Month
- Previous Month
- 2 Months ago
- 6 Months ago

This query returns the average for each month:

```
SELECT 
    avg_val1, month, year
FROM
    (SELECT 
         (sum_val1 / count) as avg_val1, month, year
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              SUM(val1) AS sum_val1, SUM(count) AS count, month, year
          FROM
              (SELECT 
                   COUNT(val1) AS count, SUM(val1) AS val1, 
                   MONTH([SnapshotDate]) AS month, 
                   YEAR([SnapshotDate]) AS year
               FROM 
                   [DC].[dbo].[KPI_Values]
               WHERE 
                   [SnapshotKey] = 'Some text here'
                   AND No = '001'
                   AND Channel = '999'
               GROUP BY 
                   [SnapshotDate]) AS sub3
          GROUP BY 
              month, year, count) AS sub2
     GROUP BY sum_val1, count, month, year) AS sub1
ORDER BY 
    year, month ASC
```

[image]

When I add the following WHERE clause I get the average for March (2 months ago):

```
WHERE month = MONTH(GETDATE())-2
  AND year = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

[image]

Now the problem is when I want to retrieve data from 6 months ago; `MONTH(GETDATE()) - 6` will output -1 instead of 12. I also have an issue with the fact that the year changes to 2016 and I am a bit unsure of how to implement the logic in my query.

I think I might be going about this wrong... Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe using BETWEEEN(GETDATE(), DATEADD(-6, GETDATE()) or something like this

Comment: @JacobH. DateAdd() has 3 parameters. `DATEADD (datepart , number , date )`. You are missing the `MONTH` datepart.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Whoops! Going to fast, not checking my own work. BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() should work. Just tested on my machine.

Comment: BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() did the trick! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the months from the date using the DATEADD function before you do your comparison. Ex:

```
WHERE SnapshotDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thank you! Placing this in my initial WHERE clause was just what was missing.

Comment: No problem! You may have to add additional dateadd arguments to get more precise dating but this should hopefully get you where you are going.

Answer (score 1):

MONTH(GETDATE()) returns an int so you can go to 0 or negative values. you need a user scalar function managing this, adding 12 when <= 0